How to change particles direction?
I'm using the Niagara system in Unreal 5.4 and don't understand how to change a particle's flow direction. I tried to add velocity and then tried changing the axis angle but no values I enter has effect on direction.
Changes I tried:

Particle initialization:

Linear Force:

